# How do I specify a single test in a file with nosetests?

Tags: python, testcase, nosetests

I have a file called test_web.py containing a class TestWeb and many methods named like  test_something().

I can run every test in the class like so:

```
$ nosetests test_web.py 
...
======================================================================
FAIL: checkout test
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/path/here/test_web.py", line 187, in test_checkout
...
```

But I can’t seem to run individual tests. These give me “No such test” errors when run in the same PWD:

```
$ nosetests test_web.py:test_checkout
$ nosetests TestWeb:test_checkout
```

What could be wrong here?

Comment: can't help you unless you can post your test cases or a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), I just tried the syntax you used with nose on my machine and it worked fine.

Answer (score 174):

You must specify it like so: `nosetests <file>:<Test_Case>.<test_method>`, or

```
nosetests test_web.py:TestWeb.test_checkout
```

See [the docs](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#selecting-tests)

Comment: Why on earth library uses ':' instead of '.'? ;)

Comment: Maybe to make it easy to delineate between a module and a class?

Comment: @omikron when I specified the file I didn't have any import errors

Comment: Wow that's terrible, classic python libraries, not a care for existing interfaces

Answer (score 21):

You can also specify a module:

```
nosetests tests.test_integration:IntegrationTests.test_user_search_returns_users
```

Comment: I don't know if it's a different version of Python or `nosetests` or what, but that syntax fails. What *does* work, though, is: `nosetests tests/test_integration:IntegrationTests.test_user_search_returns_users`, meaning - reference files as files, not Python modules, using `/` rather than `.`

Comment: @dwanderson both usages should work, as per http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#selecting-tests. Your failure could be caused by `tests` not being a module in your setup?

Comment: Ahh, that's right, I forgot an `__init__.py` in the `tests` directory. Well done! Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Specifying names on the command line like the other answers suggest does work and is useful. However, when I'm in the midst of writing tests, I often find that I want to run just the test I'm working on, and the names that I would have to write on the command line get pretty long and cumbersome to write. In such case, I prefer to use a custom decorator and flag.

I define `wipd` ("work in progress decorator") like this:

```
from nose.plugins.attrib import attr
def wipd(f):
    return attr('wip')(f)
```

This defines a decorator `@wipd` which will set the `wip` attribute on objects it decorates. For instance:

```
import unittest
class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    @wipd
    def test_something(self):
        pass
```

Then `-a wip` can be used at the command line to narrow the execution of the test to the ones marked with `@wipd`.

#### Note on names...

I'm using the name `@wipd` for the decorator rather than `@wip` to avoid this kind of problem:

```
import unittest
class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    from mymodule import wip    
    @wip
    def test_something(self):
        pass

    def test_something_else(self):
        pass
```

The `import` will make the `wip` decorator a member *of the class*, and **all** tests in the class will be selected. The `attrib` plugin checks the parent class of a test method to see if the attribute selected exists there too, and the attributes that are created and tested by `attrib` do not exist in a segregated space. So if you test with `-a foo` and your class contains `foo = "platypus"`, then all tests in the class will be selected by the plugin.

Answer (score 6):

To run multiple specific tests, you can just add them to the command line, separated by space.

```
nosetests test_web.py:TestWeb.test_checkout test_web.py:TestWeb.test_another_checkout
```

Answer (score 1):

In my tests, **specifying tests with module names do not work**

You must specify the actual path to the `.py`:

```
nosetests /path/to/test/file.py:test_function
```

This with `nose==1.3.7`

Answer (score 0):

My requirement was to run a single test in a test file that was in another **windows** directory  - this was done from the *anaconda command prompt* as follows:

ran *nosetests* from:

```
(base) C:\Users\ABC\Documents\work\
```

but *test_MyTestFile.py* and *methodsFile.py* were in:

```
 (base) C:\Users\ABC\Documents\work\daily\
```

run single test by *including path* with *quotes* as follows:

```
(base) C:\Users\ABC\Documents\work>nosetests "daily\\test_MyTestFile.py:MyTestClass.test_add_integers"
```

*test_MyTestFile.py* looked like this:

```
import methodsFile
import unittest

class MyTestClass(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_add_integers(self):
        assert methodsFile.add(5, 3) == 8

    def test_add_integers_zero(self):
        assert methodsFile.add(3, 0) == 3
```

*methodsFile.py* looked like this:

```
def add(num1, num2):
        return num1 + num2
```